# Removing element from webView

Tags: javascript, ios, swift, webview

I used this code to remove the header and other things but the problem is when I reload the page it will show the header for a second then remove it. I want the code to remove the header even in the reload.

```
private func removeElements(fromWebView webView: UIWebView) {
    self.elementsToRemove.forEach { self.removeElement(elementID: $0, fromWebView: webView) }
}

private func removeElement(elementID: String, fromWebView webView: UIWebView) {
    let removeElementIdScript = "var element = document.getElementById('\(elementID)'); element.parentElement.removeChild(element);"
    webView.stringByEvaluatingJavaScript(from: removeElementIdScript)

    let removeElementClassScript = "document.getElementsByClassName('\ . (elementID)')[0].style.display=\"none\";"
    webView.stringByEvaluatingJavaScript(from: removeElementClassScript)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can switch from `UIWebView` to `WKWebView` and your target is iOS 11+, you can use `WKContentRuleListStore` to filter the content using your arbitrary rules (just like ad blockers). Here's an example that removes top bar from stackoverflow website:

```
import UIKit
import WebKit

let contentRules = """
[
  {
    "trigger": {
      "url-filter": ".*"
    },
    "action": {
      "type": "css-display-none",
      "selector": "div.topbar"
    }
  }
]
"""

class ViewController: UIViewController {
  @IBOutlet weak var webView: WKWebView!

  override func loadView() {
    super.loadView()

    let request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "https://stackoverflow.com")!)
    WKContentRuleListStore.default().compileContentRuleList(forIdentifier: "ContentBlockingRules", encodedContentRuleList: contentRules) { rulesList, error in
      if let error = error {
        print(error)
        return
      }
      guard let rulesList = rulesList else { return }
      let config = self.webView.configuration
      config.userContentController.add(rulesList)
      self.webView.load(request)
    }
  }
}
```

You can find more about content blocking rules [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Extensions/Conceptual/ContentBlockingRules/CreatingRules/CreatingRules.html).